# Arduino IDE keywords.txt does not highlight class name KEYWORD1

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

```
###################################
# Syntax Coloring Map For LEDdigits
###################################

LEDdigits   KEYWORD1
setPins   KEYWORD2
digit     KEYWORD2
display   KEYWORD2
```

The library is functioning properly but the class name isn't highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with visualized white-spaces your text is

[image]

it should be

[image]

reference: https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/library-specification/#keywordstxt-format

Answer (score 1):

Arduino's keywords.txt syntax is pretty pedantic. It will not work if you put spaces instead of tabs to separate tokens.

Try -

```
LEDdigits    KEYWORD1
#        ^^^^ TabSpace
```

And remember to restart the IDE to see your changes.

Comment: Try removing and re-adding Tabs (to all lines). And make sure your editor is not reformatting the whitespace.